# Finding remainder with modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$10^{515}$ is divided by 7
$10^{515}\equiv$$3^{515}$ (mod 7)

$3^1\equiv$$3$ (mod 7)
$3^2\equiv$$2$ (mod 7)
$3^3\equiv$$1$ (mod 7)

$3^{515}$=$3^{3*171+2}$=$(3^3)^{171}*3^2$=$1^{171}*2$=2
so my remainder would be 2, but wolfram alpha says it should be 5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $3^3\equiv -1$ (mod 7)

Comment: How is it -1 and not 1?

Comment: $3^3 \equiv 3*(3^2) \equiv 3*2 \equiv 6 \equiv -1$ (mod 7).

Comment: $3^3=27=28\color{red}{{}-1}$

Comment: Gottcha, So how would that help me get to the remainder being 5?

Comment: **HINT**: What is $-2$ (mod $7$) equivalent to?

Comment: @Mufasa 5 (mod 7)

Comment: Exactly! :) Hopefully you have now answered your question

Answer (score 1):

[Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) would be one approach. Another one would be writing $10^2=100=$ $=2\cdot50=2\cdot(49+1)$, and $2^3=8=7+1$.